# How to pass data from parent to child component without using props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to code a reusable Vue tab component (I know there are a lot there but I'm doing this for the sake of a challenge).

The problem I am facing right now is passing data to child without using props.

The reason for this is very simple, I need the child tab element to know the current selected tab index and I don't want user who uses my component to always need to type in the props for every tab component.

For this very reason I have gone and observe how other Vue tabs library solve this issue ([bootstrap vue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/tabs/tabs.js), [vue tabs](https://github.com/cristijora/vue-tabs/blob/master/src/components/VTab.js) etc.etc.), but all I found are them accessing parent properties with `this.$parent` or `this.$children` to access child properies. And I know this is not the Vue way.

I have looked into inject and provide, it's is great but it's not reactive.

I also don't want to use Vuex because my project is too small for it and I want my component to be reusable.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What information do you want to pass to your component. I don't see any reason to reject props. Because if users do not have to type props, they have to type some thing else to make your component work in other way.

Comment: If you don't want to use `this.$parent` or `this.$child`, you cannot use vuex, because you are building a component and would rather not use props, the only solution I can see is going for `localStorage` or `cookies`, although I believe that you should go with `$child/$parent` because you are building a standalone component

Comment: @Ant I wanted to use `$child/parent` but I thought I read some where in the documentation that this is not recommended.

Comment: @LukasChen recommended maybe not, but it all has to do with the scale of your project. If you plan on using it as a plug and play component for different projects, then I don't see any other way of building it and having the required "sandboxing"

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create your own store without using Vuex:

```js
class TabStore {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: 1
    }
  }
  setIndex(value) {
    this.state.currentIndex = value
  }
}
let tabStore = new TabStore()

Vue.component('tab-item', {
  template: '#tab',
  data() {
    return { state: tabStore.state }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return { state: tabStore.state }
  },
  methods: {
    changeIndex() {
      let index = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) //<-- for the example
      tabStore.setIndex(index)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>Current Index from Main component: <strong>{{ state.currentIndex }}</strong></p>
  <tab-item></tab-item>
  <button @click="changeIndex">Change current index</button>
</div>

<template id="tab">
 <p>Current Index from Tab component: <strong>{{ state.currentIndex }}</strong></p>
</template>
```

You can use `setIndex()` from the store to change the `state.currentIndex` and you have access to this one everywhere.

Comment: Are the components reusable with each set of tab parent and child having a unique index?

Answer (score -1):

I believe learning Vuex may be of interest to you.
Vuex in simple terms acts as a 'single source of truth' for data in your Vue app.
This means any data stored in the vuex 'store' can be accesses by any component in your app. If you set the components to import your vuex store correctly, it also offers reactive bindings to any other component referencing the store which means you no longer worry about running into complex passing of properties through multiple components. Instead each component references the root stores data. (Hope that makes sense.)

This is a very high level overview, but if it sounds like it would help your project, you should really check out the [Official Documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) which is great!

Comment: sorry that I didn't state in my question but my project is to small for vuex & I want my component to be reusable on the same page